# Why sed command is unable to substitute matched string?

Tags: linux, sed

My file name 'old' contains '123 abc'. When I use the below sed command in linux terminal:

```
 sed 's:[0-9]+:& &:' <old \> new
```

new file contains same data as old that is '123 abc'.
But output should be '123 123 abc'.
I don,t know where i am wrong. Can anyone help me please......

Comment: is your problem solved now? You might consider accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Two small remarks:

- you shold use a backslash before the `+` sign
- no need to use a backslash before the `>` sign to pipe the output:

  `sed 's:[0-9]\+:& &:' old > new`

(and a minor change; but not necessary: no need for the `<` before the input file; sed knows you will give it a file.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your command to:

```
sed 's:[0-9]\+:& &:' old > new
```

OR

```
sed -r 's:[0-9]+:& &:' old > new
```

`-r` : Use extended regular expressions (in our case, for `+` to work as expected)